# Configuring Apache, Tomcat, mod_jk and mod_rewrite to serve up tomcat from top-level

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, java, mod-rewrite, mod-jk

I'm trying to set up my java app as the main component of a new site.

I have some static resources I'd like served by Apache, so I setup Apache and Mod_jk, with the following rules,

```
    JkMount /java_app* ajp13
    JkUnmount /*static/* ajp13
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/$ /java_app/ [L,PT]
```

Workers file and everything is working swell.  When I go to http://www.example.com/, I get the index file for my java app due to the rewrite rule.  If I browse around the site, I still get my java app due to mod_jk, like http://www.example.com/java_app/view/1/.

The problem: when I head back to http://www.example.com, I completely lose any session information.  If I was logged in, I'm logged out, and the links from there are getting appended with jsessionids.

How do I fix this?  Is this the proper way to connect apache and tomcat, or is there a better way?

EDIT:

To respond to the first answer,

Still a bit stuck. When I load up firebug, I see this when I navigate to `/`

```
Set-Cookie JSESSIONID=8D63C9682E39B81F669E277ED07542E1; Path=/javaapp
```

As I browse around inside the java app, I see that the same `jsessionid` stays with me - firebug says I'm sending in the request headers.

When I hit `/` again, I get this in the response,

```
Set-Cookie JSESSIONID=5DC9F39CE85AB1E71B8D87EB9D485FE9; Path=/javaapp
```

So I guess Apache forwards on my request without my cookie information, so Tomcat gives me a new one?  Can I tell mod_rewrite to say ex. `^/$ /javaapp/;jsessionid={cookie}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks both.  I agree that it is a cookie path problem, or an issue with Apache not sending the cookie info forward, or something.

I ended up making the tomcat webapp ROOT, which caused the cookie path problems to go away, along with removing the /javapp context root from the URLs a nice side affect.  I ended up with mod_proxy_ajp, as it was easy to configure, and I found some shibboleth documentation that pointed to this being the best option.

It seems like this whole space is such voodoo, and everybody comes up with their own solution, that I might as well find something that works and just run with it...

Comment: can you post your final solution for those interested?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `mod_jk2` (which is deprecated anyway), but use [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) with *ProxyPass* and *ProxyReversePass*. Much easier to configure, even your exception for static content can be expressed easily:

```
ProxyPass /statics !
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080
```

The drawback is obviously that if the Java application wants to read the client's IP address (and other client-information), it will get the Apache's address instead as he is the playing proxy. For this situations, you will need to use `mod_jk`

Comment: mod_jk is not deprecated. mod_jk2 is deprecated.

Comment: You can use `mod_proxy` and still get the client's real IP address, etc. You will likely want to enable the `RemoteIPValve` and `SSLValve` on the Tomcat side. `mod_jk` is not necessary to get this information.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's a cookie path problem. To confirm that, you may fire up your HTTP debugger and analyse the HTTP traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Set worker.worker1.sticky_session=1

I say use mod_jk, as its created especially for tomcat ajp and its well maintened ( every year thers update with new fetures)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using mod_header in your config which has functionality similar mod_rewrite but is used for modifying http headers.

To change all cookie paths from /javaapp to /

```
Header edit Set-Cookie "^(.*; Path=)/javaapp/?(.*)" $1/$2
```

Or if you wanted to change the cookie path entirely from /javaapp to say /my_java_app

```
Header edit Set-Cookie "^(.*; Path=)/javaapp/?(.*)" $1/my_java_app/$2
```